# spring boot fails to load and execute tests in java 11

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-11

I am getting the following output when executing spring boot tests using java 11.
I am also getting the exact same error when I execute

`java -jar target\application.jar`

So it's not just a maven issue.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. 
The attempt was made from the following location:

org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.<init>(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:627)
javax.annotation.Resource.lookup()Ljava/lang/String; but it does not exist. Its class, javax.annotation.Resource, is available from the following locations:


    jar:file:/C:/Users/X/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/jsr250-api/1.0/jsr250-api-1.0.jar!/javax/annotation/Resource.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/X/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.2/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar!/javax/annotation/Resource.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/X/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/jsr250-api/1.0/jsr250-api-1.0.jar
```

It seems that the wrong dependency is being loaded?
I have these configurations in `pom.xml`

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

with build configuration...

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>                        <!-- or newer version -->
    <configuration>
        <source>11</source>                            <!-- depending on your project -->
        <target>11</target>                            <!-- depending on your project -->
        <compilerArgs>
        </compilerArgs>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
            <!-- other annotation processors -->
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

What is the correct method to fix this, so that the tests execute correctly out of the box?

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.annotation.Resource

**edit**

I have also tried:

```
<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </extension>
        <extension>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: And it works for older/other versions of java?

Comment: what version of spring boot are you using? not all of them are java9+ compatible

Comment: I have updated the question with the details, using the latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this if you will;

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>                      
    <configuration>
        <source>11</source>         
        <target>11</target>          
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

I'm using this kind declaration to add `javax.activation-api` and `plexus-archiver` to `dockerfile-maven-plugin` plugin. But my `spring-boot-starter-parent` version is `2.1.4.RELEASE` and `maven-compiler-plugin` version is `3.8.0`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it's still loading the wrong Resource.class

Comment: I also updated to version 3.8.0 of maven-compiler-plugin

Comment: I have updated the question I am also having this problem just executing the jar.

Comment: it was being caused by another dependency in the POM mvn -e -X and I found it.